# DAX percent of total by category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two identical table visuals and a measure calculating percent for category.

```
% = 
DIVIDE(
    [m_SalesValue]
    ,CALCULATE([m_SalesValue], ALLSELECTED('Table'[Category]))
    ,BLANK()
)
```

When I select (highlight) one category, say banana, then the other visual shows unexpected percent value for category. The expected value is 0.25 but it shows 1.00. How should I modify the measure to get the expected results.

[image]

Getting the challenge to higher level, let's assume that both visuals have been initially cross filtered by some unspecified dimension, say fruits. That is why I used `ALLSELECTED` instead of `ALL`.

Here is source table:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSiwoyElV0lEyVYrViVZKSswDQiDXAsxNzkgtKqoEcs3B3PLEktSi3NSc/DygkKGRUmwsAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Category = _t, SalesValue = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category", type text}, {"SalesValue", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: Including your starting data this way is pretty handy, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use ALLEXCEPT and identify the cross-filters that you still want to apply.  Your example suggests 'Fruits' so that's what I included below.

```
% = 
DIVIDE(
    [m_SalesValue]
    ,CALCULATE([m_SalesValue], ALLEXCEPT(Table, 'Table'[Fruits]))
    ,BLANK()
)
```

Comment: Does `ALLEXCEPT` allow to list all potential dimensions that the user may (but not must) initially filter? Anyway, it looks promising:-)

Comment: Yes.  ALLEXCEPT basically makes the statement:  "Clear all filters except for these" and then you can list them out.  So, it's fine to include columns that aren't being filtered right now, but might be someday.  The caveat is that it all has to be on the same table which can be a bit troublesome.